# Using Excel VBA Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs in table

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs in a table but I cannot get it to work.

I have tried the following code:

```
pData = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(potdata.Range("O:O"), "<>" & "", potdata.Range("B:B"), xIni, potdata.Range("V:V"), xMdr, potdata.Range("P:P"), "Ordre")
```

The problem is this part ***potdata.Range("O:O"), "<>" & ""***

I want it to count only when Range("O:O") is not empty but it still counts both empty and not empty.

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks!

**SOLVED!**

I solved it by first counting all rows and then I subtracted the ones empty in column O.

```
pData = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(potdata.Range("B:B"), xIni, potdata.Range("V:V"), xMdr, potdata.Range("P:P"), "Ordre")
tData = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(potdata.Range("O:O"), "", potdata.Range("B:B"), xIni, potdata.Range("V:V"), xMdr, potdata.Range("P:P"), "Ordre")
pData - tData
```

Comment: Doesn't `<>` alone count non-blank? Do you have formulas in column O returning `""`?

Comment: I guess cause it counts all cells also the ones that are empty. There are no formulas in column O. All cells are empty.